# Prepopulating Edit page for the row (Item) which has two keys in SAP UI5

Tags: odata, sapui5

This is my Item level page which has two Keys `Request ID , Profile ID`.

By selecting the item and on pressing the `Edit` Button, i should display the edit page with the data.

[image]

Code for `Edit Button` press

```
this.getRouter().getTargets().display("CreateCandidate", {
            mode: "update",
            objectPath: sObjectPath
        });
```

Here I'm getting

> sObjectPath = "ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=1)"

**My** **manifest.json**

```
"CreateCandidate":{
                "viewName": "CreateCandidate",
                "viewId": "cand_creation",
                "viewLevel":2
            },
```

In the `edit` page, what should i bind to the `FORM` & what should be my pattern URL for the edit page.

For header row, we will give `ZENTITY_SET/1` kind of.

But if we have two keys, how we will give the Pattern . Is it like `ZENTITY_SET/1/2` ?  please guide me regarding this

**My ODATA read query :**

```
/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZRECRUITMENT_TRACKER_APP_SRV/
ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=2)?$format=xml
```

**My OData Response:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-
<entry
 xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xml:base="http://ttpl001.truspeq.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZRECRUITMENT_TRACKER_APP_SRV/"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <id>http://ttpl001.truspeq.com:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/ZRECRUITMENT_TRACKER_APP_SRV/ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=1)</id>
 <title type="text">ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=1)</title>
 <updated>2018-07-19T20:09:00Z</updated>
 <category scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" term="ZRECRUITMENT_TRACKER_APP_SRV.ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATE"/>
 <link title="ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATE" href="ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=1)" rel="self"/>
 <link title="TOSALESDATA" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" href="ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet(RegNo=1,ProId=1)/TOSALESDATA" rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/TOSALESDATA"/>-
 <content type="application/xml">-
  <m:properties>
   <d:RegNo>1</d:RegNo>
   <d:ProId>1</d:ProId>
   <d:NameOfCan>ROCKY</d:NameOfCan>
   <d:Exp>4 YEAR</d:Exp>
   <d:CurrentCtc>45000</d:CurrentCtc>
   <d:ExpCtc>750000</d:ExpCtc>
   <d:NoticePeriod>3 MONTH</d:NoticePeriod>
   <d:CurrentLoc>KOLKATA</d:CurrentLoc>
   <d:CurrentCom>TCS</d:CurrentCom>
   <d:PassportDet>HHHWWQQ77</d:PassportDet>
   <d:PhoneNum>77778585</d:PhoneNum>
   <d:Email>ROCKYKUMAR@TCS.COM</d:Email>
   <d:SkypeId>7745</d:SkypeId>
  </m:properties>
 </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem? What is doing wrong? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: on clicking EDIT button, it should go to next page and populate the selected row's data .

Comment: In the edit page, what should i bind to the FORM & what should be my pattern URL for the edit page.For header row, we will give ZENTITY_SET/1 kind of.But if we have two keys, how we will give the Pattern . Is it like ZENTITY_SET/1/2 ?  please guide me regarding this

Comment: As far as routing goes, you can define it as you see fit, as long as you respect the pattern you put in the manifest.json file afterwards when navigating. Since the Edit page is working on top of a specific entity, I suggest calling view.bindElement on the onInit method. That way all binding will become relative to the entity you just bound which makes it easy to fill the form with data binding on your view.

Comment: @Kyle provided a ver good answer for your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs for configuring the router
[here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/2366345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef)

in manifest.json:

```
...
"routes" : [
    {
        name: "createCandidate",
        pattern: "create/{RegNo}-{ProId}",
        target: "CreateCandidate"
    }
],
"targets": {
    "CreateCandidate": {
        "viewName": "CreateCandidate",
        "viewLevel": 2
},
....
```

then to nav to that view:

```
oRouter.navTo("createCandidate", {
    RegNo: 1
    ProId: 1
})
```

then in the CreateCandidate controller

```
_onPatternMatched: function(oEvent) {
    // get the params RegNo and ProId from the event object - {RegNo: 1, ProId: 1}
    var oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments"); 

    //use the ODataModel to create a binding path from the values
    var sBindingPath = this.getView().getModel().createKey("/ZRECRUITMENT_CANDIDATESet", oArgs);

    //Bind your view to the binding path
    this.getView().bindElement(sBindingPath); 
}

onInit: function() {
     //get the route object from the router
     var oRoute = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("createCandiate");

     //attach an event to the route which is fired when the route pattern is matched
     oRoute.attachPatternMatched(this._onPatternMatched, this);
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much @kyle

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the ob_start(ob_gzhandler) function? If so and If you output any content above the ob_start(ob_gzhandler) function, you'll get this error. You can don't use this function or don't output content above this function. The ob_gzhandler callback function will determine what type of content encoding the browser will accept and will return its output accordingly. So if you output content above this function, the content's encoding maybe different from the output content of ob_gzhandler and that cause this error.